# Rails is not removing some comments from the javascripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm ussing the assets pipeline in Rails but the comments in the jquery and jquery-ujs files are not being removed.

It is compressing every other js and css file correctly though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which comments aren't being removed, copyright ones starting with `/*!`? (If so, that's by design).

Comment: @pjumble yes, those. How do I remove them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Uglifier](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier) used by default in the rails asset pipeline has a config option `:copyright` used to preserve the copyright comments.

You can [turn it off](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2796#issuecomment-1970130), however, [legally](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45033/can-i-minify-javascript-that-requires-copyright-notice) you need to put the copyright somewhere, so if you remove the comment you'll have to put it somewhere else (visible).

Comment: Oh I see. Well I tried adding /*! to other libraries but the comments are still being removed.

Comment: After looking at the [uglifier source](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/blob/master/lib/uglifier.rb#L71) it seems to actually count any comments before the first line of code as a copyright comment, rather than using `/*!` (used by YUICompressor).

Comment: The line is `encode_regexp(/Copyright/i)`, it will look for the Copyright word in a comment.